# Extract vectors from list to dataframe columns

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested

I have a list that contains vectors of strings like this:

```
A <- list(c("A", "1"), c("G", "2"), c("T", "6"), c("A", "1"), c("A", "1"), 
          c("A", "1"), c("A", "1"), c("A", "2"), c("A", "2"), c("A", "2"), 
          c("A", "2"), c("A", "3"), c("X", "3"), c("A", "4"), c("A", "4"), 
          c("A", "4"), c("A", "5"), c("A", "5"), c("A", "2"), c("A", "6"))
```

I want to creat two columns in a dataframe, one with the first elements ("A", "G", ...) and one with the second element (1, 2, ...).

Comment: The example list you provided is not nested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `rbind` the `list` elements with `do.call` and then convert the `matrix` to `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, A))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also `unlist` A.

```
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(A), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
```